# Install SQLite into Eclipse to use with Java

Tags: java, database, eclipse, sqlite, installation

I am trying to build a piece of software that has its own inbuilt, freestanding database.

I have decided that SQLite is the best option for me to use.

The problem is that I cannot find any clear instructions on how to install it into Eclipse. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Download driver  JDBC  https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc

Installation & Configuration

Import driver JDBC in your project

Add Referenced Libraries clicking on the file  jar -> Build Path -> Add to Build Path